# iOS - UISearchBar with results in Popover View (using UIViewController from storyboard)

Tags: ios, delegates, uisearchbar, uipopover

I am having some trouble passing the search bar text to the popover view.
The flow is like this:

1. Parent view has a toolbar with a uisearchbar
2. Parent view is connected with a segue to another subclassed uiviewcontroller, and displays this as a popover from the searchbar
3. The popover viewcontroller uses a tableview to display the data I want filtered (table view is setup and works fine, method that filters the results is setup and works fine).
4. Parent view is the delegate of the searchbar and receives the text everytime the search term is changed

How can I pass the search term to the popover?
I setup a custom delegate in the parentview with a method that should pass the search term to the delegate method, but that method is not being called in the popover.

*My best **guess** is that I need to somewhere specify that the popover uses my custom delegate (i.e Declaring ThisView.delegate = self, but this is a problem since the child view is created by a segue)

Here is how the popover is displayed:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueSearchResults"]) {
        self.searchPopover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        self.searchPopover.delegate = self;//To avoid confusion, this is the popover's delegate to notify the parent view when it has closed, etc.
    }
}
```

Here is the delegate protocol:

```
@class VideoViewController;
@protocol VideoViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)searchTermChanged:(NSString *)value;
@end

@interface VideoViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>{
    __weak id <VideoViewDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <VideoViewDelegate> delegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a public method (or property) on the popover controller, and whenever the search text changes, send the new text to the popover using said method.  Or you make the popover controller as the search bar's delegate.